# From select option tag define the database to be created

Tags: php, html

The html form action attribute = "uploadone.php". The form has an option element value attribute = 'Red'. There are a number of databases to be created this way. I can add parameters to the URL as below but it gets too cumbersome as the select is pretty long. What’s the best solution in this case. Please any help on this. Thanks upfront

```
 <form action="uploadone.php" method="post"                
 enctype="multipart/form-data">

 <select name="unoone" class="unoone ui-btn ui-mini" data-role="none"     data-native-menu="false" required>
  <option value="">My Task</option>
  <option option value="Red">Red</option>
  <option option value="Blue">Blue</option>
  <option option value="Black">Black</option>
  <option option value="White">White</option>    

 <input type="submit" value="Submit" name="submit" />
  </form>
```

uploadone.php

```
  include 'Includes/conDB.php';

 // 'Red' the option element value attribute
 // Select a database to use 
 // T1 and T2 have a LEFT JOIN

 if ($_POST['unoone'] == 'Red') {

include "Includes/T1.php"; 
include "Includes/T2.php";

}
```

Comment: `action="uploadone.php?name=’Red’"` What's with the additional quotes? Remove them and do `action="uploadone.php?name=Red"` instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you should get values ,because your form has post method attribute.
as

```
$_POST['unone']
```

instead of

```
$_GET['name']
```

and change the action of form is as uploadone.php

Comment: Profound thanks Rohit! Its a blue sky scenario